# ubuntu internet problem

Tags: internet

I just installed Ubuntu.
I have no set correctly my internet configuration.

Here are my settings:

```
ifconfig:
 eth0 (inet adr 192.168.10.101)
 eth1 (no ip address)
 lo (inet adr 127.0.0.1)
```

Output of my `/etc/network/interfaces:`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0 inet static 
     address 10.1.18.16
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     gateway 10.1.18.1
     broadcast 10.1.18.255
```

when I did service network-manager restart, my ifconfig is changed to the above output.

```
ping 8.8.8.8 fails
ping www.google.com fails
```

my `/etc/resolv.conf is this`

nameserver

Any help, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem like this:
First, I edited this file: `/etc/network/interfaces` with my valid data (I do not want to show them here)
Second, I edited this file: `/etc/resolv.conf` where I added my servername and its address.
Third, I edited this file: `/etc/hosts` where I added my IP address and my machine's name.
Finally, I run this command: `sudo service network - interface start / stop / restart INTERFACE = eth0`